# RBAC for system to system access

Tags: authentication, authorization, privilege-escalation, system-compromise, rbac

- An organisations has multiple service tiers. One of the services in a core tier exposes APIs to the tier above. The core tier services do RBAC, consequently an end customer token is required in order to access their APIs.
- There are 2 categories of users - internal users & external customers.
- Some microservices on the tier above need access to internal APIs while they serve requests on behalf of an external customers. e.g. internal users can search details of external customers via SearchCustomer(id). Some micrservices also need to invoke the same API while serving an external customer request (i.e. the current logged in user is an external customer), so that the core tier services return 403 based on Auth header validation.

[image]

What could be the better solution? Should the core tier services should extend their security matrix to allow system level access via a client credentials grant (e.g. admin API kind of access for systems)? Is this an anti-pattern where it smells something wrong with the API design?

In other words; [end user] --> [front end] --> [microservice] --> [core service]

- The microservice accesses upstream core-service - to serve an end user request
- From the upstream perspective, should the microservice have same privileges as the end user or should the microservice be considered in a system to system context?